# No grub kernel entries after upgrade to 20.04 - system boots into BIOS

Tags: boot, grub2, upgrade, uefi, 20.04

I just upgraded my Thinkpad X1 from 19.10 to 20.04. 
As described in the upgrade process, at the reboot I git the MOK Manager menu, and enrolled the ubuntu key with the password I had set before.

Then I expected the system would boot into grub and ask me for an encryption key for the encrpyted lvm partition.

But instead the screen turned black, the system rebooted again, and went into BIOS Setup mode without me doing anything. No grub menu, nothing.

After turning it off completely, and turning it on, always the same thing happens: 
The BIOS Logo appears, and after a few seconds, when I expect the system to boot,a black screen comes up for a few seconds, and then the system stops and reboots into BIOS Setup again.

I just started to use Linux on the laptop again after being on a mac for a while, so basically I know how to adjust grub command line on errors - but here no grub menu ever appears and I don't really know where to start fixing it. I tried turning UEFI BIOS Secure boot off(I have not much experience with UEFI, as it didn't exist when I was last using Linux on a laptop), but that doesn't change anything.

UPDATE:

In the meantime I found out that the problem seems to be a grub.conf that has no kernel entries.

Running update grub in a chroot with the root filesystem mounted after booting a live system (plus required system directories like proc and sys) I still don't get any kernel entries, even though 3 kernels are available.
I currently don't really know how to make grub find the kernels.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No explanation what really happened, but solved for me:

After forced reinstalling grub2-common, kernel menuentries where generated again and the system could boot.

Answer (score 1):

I had a very similar issue where new kernel entries would not appear in the grub after upgrading to Ubuntu 22.04.
I reinstalled the grub2 packages and everything worked. The link [1] was very helpful.

```
sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get --reinstall install grub-common grub-efi-amd64 os-prober
```

Note that these commands are for EFI-Installation. First determine if you are using EFI or BIOS-Installation, then use the appropriate commands.

[1] https://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/GRUB_2/Reparatur/

Comment: thanks! that confirms my findings apparently still work and thanks for adding the commands necessary that I didnt write out. in my case only the grub common was necessary to be reinstalled.